# Strange ellipsis appearing in UINavigationBar

Tags: ios7, uinavigationbar

I have implemented a navigation item with a left button, a title view, and a right button. The back button is set to "hides".

On some left transitions, a blue ellipsis appears momentarily.

[image]

Any ideas as to what this is and how to get rid of it?

Comment: I was also seeing this, and it seemed to only be happening when pushing between VCs that both had set hidesBackButton. I followed @livings124's advice: remove "hidesBackButton = YES" and add a custom left bar button. It didn't work with an empty left bar button, but a single space title (" ") worked. It looks like you might already have some custom left bar buttons, so I'm not sure if this helps.

Comment: @altruic - This was exactly my situation.  I resolved by adding the blank leftBarButtonItem to each navBar.  I actually titled them "back" but set their textColor to clearColor.  I also set each VC's navigationItem.tintColor = UIColor.clearColor(), which ONLY affects the coloring of the system's backBarButtonItem.  This completely resolved the issue for me.  To note, sometimes I received ellipses, and sometimes it was the title of the bottom-most viewController in the navController stack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made it go away by setting the tint colour to transparent:

> self.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];

Answer (score 13):

I fixed this by not calling:

self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;

By setting a custom left bar button item, but not calling that method/setting it to NO, the ellipsis doesn't appear. I assume this is an Apple bug.

Comment: Wow - that took a very long time to find and is very misleading ... Thanks !

Answer (score 8):

If the navigation controller stack's parent view controller has a navigation item with a custom titleView, you must set the title to `@""` for it to render properly during first pop.

Comment: Good, simple, "low-tech" way of handling the problem. Worked for me in Swift 1.1 on iOS 8 as well.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I needed to use `hidesBackButton` so livings124 solution didn't work for me. Instead, calling

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backItem.title = @"";
```

in `viewWillAppear:` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

may be your current viewcontroller's title too long. 
You can set the pushed viewcontroller's title in viewdidappear method.work for me.
also please check if you have or  not set the attribute like this 'self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes' if you do have,please comment it.then try again.

Answer (score 0):

#### iOS 9, XCode 7.3.1:

In my case (`UIBarButtonItem` with a custom view), I fixed  this by calling `sizeToFit()` on the custom view in `viewDidLoad`.

#### tl;dr

I add a `UIBarButtonItem` in IB for the segue and as a visual cue...but in code, I replaced it with a `UIBarButtonItem(customView: myCustomButton)`.

*speculation:* Since `UIBarButtonItems` are not views, my customView was being loaded into NavigationBar (but) without IB there to give it dimensions, so it had the default for a `UIView` -- `CGRect.zero`.